# Estimates using solution of PDE in Fourier space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Lets suppose that I have the following system
$$
u_t = Au_{xx}+ Bu. 
$$
If I solve this using Fourier transforms, I will get something like
$$
\hat{u}_t = D(\xi) \hat{u}, 
$$
where $\xi$ is the Fourier variable. So the solution will be $\hat{u}(t,\xi) = e^{tD(\xi)}\hat{u}_0(\xi)$. I want to estimate the solution in $H^s$ with $s>1/2$ and I would like to get a estimate of the form $$||u(t)||_{H^s} \leq ke^{-ct}||u_0||_{H^s}.$$

So I have a question: My teacher told us in class that it is enough to obtain the estimate $$\sup_{\xi \in \mathbb{R}} ||e^{t D(\xi)}|| \leq k e^{-ct}.$$
But I don't see how this estimate (which involves the Fourier variable) will be enough to get the desired estimate (which involves the original variable).

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What definition of the Sobolev norm on $H^s$ are you using?

Comment: I am using the following norm $\|f\|_{H^s\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)}:=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(1+|\xi|^2\right)^s|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d \xi\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Ohh now i see what is happening, i just have to put the fourier solution in the norm of the original solution and pull out the exponential in the integral with the supremum and that will be all.

Comment: @AlekMurt: Right! If you had recalled all the relevant definitions in the question, the solution would have dawned on you while you were writing, which is something that happened to me several times.